# Arduino hangs during multiple http requests on Linux but not on Windows

Tags: c++, linux, apache, networking, arduino

i have a problem when i send http requests from the arduino to linux mysql server. It randomly hangs after some requests (~150) but on windows it runs smoothly.

Because of this i am thinking that the problem is not on the arduino code but somewhere else.

The linux server runs on a raspberry pi (Raspbian).

Any suggestions?

The arduino code [HERE](https://github.com/mKontakis/Arduino/blob/master/WeatherMeters/ver8/ver8.ino)

```
 if(!getPage(server,serverPort)) Serial.print(F("Fail "));



byte getPage(IPAddress ipBuf,int thisPort)
{
  int inChar;


  Serial.print(F("connecting..."));

  if(client.connect(ipBuf,thisPort))
  {
    Serial.println(F("connected"));

    strcpy(outBuf,"GET /write3.php?value0=");
    itoa(value0,tBuf,10);
    strcat(outBuf,tBuf);

    strcat(outBuf,"&value1=");
    itoa(dht_humidity,tBuf,10);
    strcat(outBuf,tBuf);

    strcat(outBuf,"&value2=");
    itoa(temperature,tBuf,10);
    strcat(outBuf,tBuf);

    strcat(outBuf,"&value3=");
    itoa(pressure,tBuf,10);
    strcat(outBuf,tBuf);

    strcat(outBuf,"&value4=");
    itoa(altitude,tBuf,10);
    strcat(outBuf,tBuf);

    strcat(outBuf,"&value5=");
    itoa(gust,tBuf,10);
    strcat(outBuf,tBuf);

    strcat(outBuf,"&value6=");
    itoa(dir,tBuf,10);
    strcat(outBuf,tBuf);

    strcat(outBuf,"&value7=");
    itoa(rain,tBuf,10);
    strcat(outBuf,tBuf);

    strcat(outBuf,"&value8=");
    itoa(knots,tBuf,10);
    strcat(outBuf,tBuf);


    client.write(outBuf);
    client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: 192.168.1.3");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
```

EDIT: Just hanged at DEBUG___3

```
Serial.println("DEBUG___2");
client.write(outBuf);
Serial.println("DEBUG___3");
client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
Serial.println("DEBUG___4");
client.println("Host: 192.168.1.3");
Serial.println("DEBUG___5");
client.println("Connection: close");
client.println();
```

I captured the network traffic with wireshark when it hanged:

(Large pics: [hanged http request](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15854314/arduino_wireshark_1.png) ---- [successfull http request](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15854314/arduino_wireshark_2.png))

Here is the http request that hanged

[image]

And here is a successful request:

[image]

Any ideas guys? Still stuck there !!!

Comment: How is `outBuf` declared/defined/allocated? Same with `tBuf`? Also, technically the HTTP protocol needs `\r\n` to terminate records, are you sure `println` does the right thing?

Comment: char outBuf[128];
char tBuf[16];

Comment: Then you can overflow `outBuf`, the possible maximum length of characters you can add is larger than the size of the buffer.

Comment: Yes this is not the problem

Comment: can you attach your process in GDB and take the check out and share the call stack of all threads at the time of hang?

Comment: use serial.println() to get where the code hangs.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you are certain the outBuf is not overflowed (it is smaller than maximum possible request string size and you are using strcat (source of all evil))

The server may timeout in the long time between when the connection is opened, and when you actually send any bytes.  Preconstruct the outBuf so that it is ready to go when the connection opens.

```
strncat(outBuf,...,127);
... request is fully constructed

if(client.connect(ipBuf,thisPort)) {
  client.write(outBuf);
  client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
  client.println("Host: 192.168.1.3");
...
```

To the server, the connection that is SYN'd but not used is a resource to be recovered.  The Arduino will be so slow, it will look like an idle connection.  Also a SYN flood is an old denial of service vector that most servers will protect against.

A difference in the timeout values would explain why the Linux and Win based server act different.  You could confirm this by running Wireshark on the traffic.  If the server is timing out on the Arduino, you will see this sequence:

- the SYN handshake proceed between server and Arduino
- a little time passes
- a RST from the server indicating the connection is dead
- the Arduino sends the request string to the now dead connection
- the Arduino program hangs at the client.write() because the connection state is out of 
  sync
- the client will probably be retrying - you should see some retransmissions

Comment: That last column of numbers is the packet size (yes?). 1514 on the GET looks like you overflowed a buffer and lost the zero terminator.  Without that, the write() just keeps sending the random bytes in RAM until it finds a zero.

Comment: And look at all the wasted keep alive.  Server: hello Arduno: hi Server: what? Ard: hold on, I'm thinking  Server: now? Ard: hold on Server: really? Arduino: just a little longer Server: dude? Arduino: I'm grinding strings here, keep your pants on Server: now? Arduino: crimmey, I'm a 16 MHz microcontroller Server: umm...

Comment: The strlen function at the time arduino hanged reported 105. Why wireshark reported such a big value ?

Comment: You will need to look at the bytes in the packet to see what is being sent.  Force a terminator on the buffer before the write() with outBuf[127] = '\0'; to see if behavior changes.  Create a block of memory byte zeros[10] = {0,.. after outBuff and check that it stays all zero.  If any of the zeros[i] change, something is overflowing.  You may be simply running out of stack space.